# How can I find a USB barcode scanner hardware ID while scanning?

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-scanner, hardware-id

I have a multiple USB barcode scanners and keyboards hooked up to PC at the same time. My **C#** project requires that I should perform specific task depending upon from which barcode scanner I am reading in (Barcode scanner are associated with tasks).

Current Status: When I scan using one of the hooked up scanner, I am able to get all characters and store it, but I am unable to find from which scanner it is coming in?

My thought: Can we find hardware ID of the barcode scanner while scanning? Or any of your advice will do best. Thanks.

Comment: If you get the data from scanner as keyboard events, **NO**

Comment: Okay, then how should I read in? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I was thinking, even if I read in as keyboard events, still is there not a way to find out which port/USB I am reading in? Because every event has a sender or something like that? Sorry if it is confusing:)

Comment: You need to read the barcode scanner documentation or talk to their support team.  They probably have a "simple API" that you're currently using, which just gives you barcode data and nothing else.  They *may* have a more robust API for getting down and dirty with USB or serial stuff.  But you'll need to look through the documentation to find out.  If not, then look for another scanner that fits your requirements for your project.

Comment: Check your scanner manual/programming guide.  Some scanners let you set a prefix (some call it header) code before the scanner sends the data to the computer.  Maybe set each scanner with a different prefix and then parse it out in your application?